# Disable default ASP.NET error pages, show default IIS error pages instead (remote only)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I disable the default ASP.NET error pages, but not the error pages from IIS, for remote requests only? Basically [`HttpResponse.TrySkipIisCustomErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.tryskipiiscustomerrors(v=vs.110).aspx) but in reverse.

I've tried calling [`Response.Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525713(v=vs.90).aspx) to remove the default ASP.NET error page from the response, and configuring my IIS error pages using [`existingResponse="PassThrough"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690497(v=vs.90).aspx). While that stops the default ASP.NET error pages from showing, it doesn't show the IIS error pages. ([I've opened a separate question about `PassThrough`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634170/existingresponse-passthrough-not-working))

Answer (score 0):

First Solution:
 for IIS 7+ is to use the  tag within  that defines the error page behavior not per page/request but globally for the application in your web.config as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom"/>
  [...]
</system.webServer>
```

2nd Solution:
disable this behavior is to set Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors in the error controller like this:

```
[HandleError]
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult NotFound()
  {
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    return View("NotFound");
  }

}
```

Comment: 1. I am already using `<httpErrors>`. ASP.NET overrules these. 2. `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` is the opposite of what I want to achieve. I **want** the IIS errors, instead of the ASP.NET errors.