# <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"> not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

My Web.config contains the following:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="PassThrough">
    <clear />
    <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error" />
    <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/error" />
</httpErrors>
```

I don't want to display the default ASP.NET error pages, so I clear my response like so:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Response.StatusCode >= 400) {
        Response.Clear();
    }
}
```

This stops the default ASP.NET error pages from showing. Unfortunately, my custom error pages don't show up either. Even though my response is empty, `PassThrough` doesn't execute my custom error page path (no breakpoints are hit). If I use `existingResponse="Replace"`, everything works fine, but why doesn't it work with `PassThrough`?

Comment: Same issue. Did you ever figure it out

Comment: @TerranceJackson I gave up on `PassThrough` and added `existingResponse="Replace"` to my Web.Release.config transform. I do not recommend using `Replace` when debugging, unless you specifically want to debug the custom error pages.